# How does Docker interact with a storage device?

Tags: docker

I've read about Docker's layered file system. I don't understand how it ultimately interacts with the storage device. My understanding is that a file system manages a partition of a storage device. Does Docker create a new partition for each container you run on the underlying device and install the layered file system onto that partition?

Sorry, I've had trouble even articulating this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post
[How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine)
contains some excellent answers.

An
[answer by Ken Cochrane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048358/165358)
says this:

> Docker originally used [LinuX
> Containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/) (LXC), but later
> switched to runC (formerly known as libcontainer), which runs in the
> same operating system as its host. This allows it to share a lot of
> the host operating system resources. Also, it uses a layered
> filesystem ([AuFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/)) and manages
> networking.
>
> AuFS is a layered file system, so you can have a read only part and a
> write part which are merged together. One could have the common parts
> of the operating system as read only (and shared amongst all of your
> containers) and then give each container its own mount for writing.

Another
[answer by L0j1k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36393773/165358)
explains layering in more detail:

> As far as the filesystem used by each of those container processes,
> Docker uses [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS)-backed
> images, which is what you're downloading when you do a `docker pull ubuntu`.
>
> Each "image" is just a series of layers and related metadata. The
> concept of layering is very important here. Each layer is just a
> change from the layer underneath it. For example, when you delete a
> file in your Dockerfile while building a Docker container, you're
> actually just creating a layer on top of the last layer which says
> "this file has been deleted".
>
> Incidentally, this is why you can delete a big file from your
> filesystem, but the image still takes up the same amount of disk
> space. The file is still there, in the layers underneath the current
> one. Layers themselves are just tarballs of files.
>
> You can test this out with `docker save --output /tmp/ubuntu.tar ubuntu` and then `cd /tmp && tar xvf ubuntu.tar`. Then you can take a
> look around. All those directories that look like long hashes are
> actually the individual layers. Each one contains files (`layer.tar`)
> and metadata (`json`) with information about that particular layer.
> Those layers just describe changes to the filesystem which are saved
> as a layer "on top of" its original state.
>
> When reading the "current" data, the filesystem reads data as though
> it were looking only at the top-most layers of changes. That's why the
> file appears to be deleted, even though it still exists in "previous"
> layers, because the filesystem is only looking at the top-most layers.
>
> This allows completely different containers to share their filesystem
> layers, even though some significant changes may have happened to the
> filesystem on the top-most layers in each container. This can save you
> a ton of disk space, when your containers share their base image
> layers. However, when you mount directories and files from the host
> system into your container by way of volumes, those volumes "bypass"
> the UnionFS, so changes are not stored in layers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, but I think it still doesn't quite answer my question (unless what I really need to ask is how union mounts work). "Normally" a filesystem manages data on a partition, right? Does UnionFS get installed on the same partition on top of the existing file system?

Comment: It's not really installed, just emulated, partly in memory and partly on disk. It's the same as a virtual disk which is one file on the host, but in the guest it looks like a whole disk. Unchanged lower layers are even saved as tarballs.

Comment: OK that makes sense. But I thought Docker containers are in the end just processes, and they would be able to make system calls to work with files. What part of the system is responsible for doing something like trapping those system calls and instead going to the virtual disk?

Comment: In the end some files are on the virtual disk and some are finally real files on the disk. The Docker thin virtualization runtime is responsible for translating everything. The API that the image is using may not even exist on the host, for example a Linux image on Windows, and the runtime is the translator.